# How to add a select all button to a custom Listview

Tags: android

I have a custom listView in my app I would like to implement my select all button I have created.

My ListView looks like.

[(Image)(Text)(CheckBox)]

I have looked at some similar questions, the most common answer was with the user of the `notifyDataSetChanged ()` method, iv'e tried researching and implementing without any luck, I was wondering can you think of a way round it or give me an example of how I can implement the method

Comment: Would your select all button be to check every list item within the ListView?

Comment: Sorry to be vague, no it would check every CheckBox

Comment: No problem, see the answer I provided below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get the above answer to work, so I used parts of another answer and found the answer.

I added this this globally.

```
ListView list;
//\\ 0 = None set \\// 1 = Select all \\// 2 = Un-Select all//\\
int selState = 0;
```

Then in the onClick method I used

```
        selState = 2;
        list.invalidateViews();
```

selState being equal to what function you want to do

In the Adapter, this is final part of code

```
switch(selState)
   {
   ...     
   case 2:
       CheckBox.setChecked(false);
       break;      
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of doing this would be to iterate through the ListView to get each item View, then check it off. I have provided some sample code below given that you are able to acquire the ListView as sampleListView and have an id of the checkbox of checkBoxId:

```
// Loop through all the items in the list view
for(int viewIndex = 0; viewIndex < sampleListView.getCount(); viewIndex++)
{
    // Get the current list item
    View listItem = sampleListView.getChildAt(sampleListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() + viewIndex);

    // Get the checkbox within the list item
    CheckBox currentBox = (CheckBox)listItem.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxId);

    // Check the checkbox
    currentBox.setChecked(true);
}
```

You could place this code within the OnClickListener() of the button and it should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, however I geta Null Pointer exception when I click the button, the CheckBox ID perfectly matches the one created in XML so Im not sure why. (The 8th line of your answer)